# look through array assign values into cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2d-array like this below. There are 26 values from 1-26, but also "bigger" categories, e.g. 2nd value: "Important", "very important", "extremely important", and are all classified as "check".

Can I integrate this into this Array like adding after "important: priority (1,3)? Or (2,3) Sorry, I am starting with Arrays.... I do not fully understand this yet. The values I then want to populate into columns. Example, if column = 1 then column2 = "Important" and column3 = "check" and so on.

```
Dim Priority(1 To 26, 1 To 2)
Priority(1, 1) = 1: Priority(1, 2) = "Important"
```

Comment: Hi, this question is very difficult to understand. Please can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I added into Array like (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) and did the looking with 2 For Each Loops...like this (maybe not very effective, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

```
  For Each Zelle In Range(Cells(FirstRow + 2, 14), Cells(LastRow, 14))
   Zelle.Offset(0, 1) = Application.VLookup(Zelle, Priority, 3, False)
   Zelle.Value = Application.VLookup(Zelle, Priority, 2, False)
   'Zelle = IIf(IsError(Zelle), "???", "Zelle")
    Next Zelle
```

it checks CellX and then goes directly to CellX+1 and so on...I am sure this could be also done with For i Loop